# Зацикливание событий

Tags: php, webhook

У меня есть вебхук, который отправляет на url JSON о событие изменения на сайте.
После получения события, я обновляю сущность на сайте и после обновления сущности дергается вебхук и образуется цикл.
Как это можно пофиксить на PHP? Нет сохранения состояния между запросами. 
Пользоваться БД не могу, пробовал создавать файлы, но допустим при массовом добавление/обновление объектов, они могут не успевать отпускать дескриптор.
Так что вариант с сессиями и куками тоже отпадает потому что вебхук их тащить не будет...

Comment: первую то хуку кто инициирует, с чего этот цикл начинается то? Программно вы не можете определить, что сейчас у вас обрабатывается хука, и не надо дергать хуку рекурсивно?и где вы объекты этих храните, если не можете пользоваться БД ?